# Random Number Generation within range with different distribution in Java

Tags: java, random, distribution

I want to generate Random number in different range. For example range 10^14 in Java with different distribution like log, normal, binomial etc. Is there any particular library for the same. I found discussion on colt and math uncommon library. But is it safe enough to generate values as int and then multiply by the corresponding range suffix. What is best practice for the same.

Answer (score 2):

Apache Commons Math has a [RandomDataImpl](http://commons.apache.org/math/api-2.2/org/apache/commons/math/random/RandomDataImpl.html) class that does nextBinomial, nextExponential and some other types (above my head unfortunately).

Hopefully that gets you everything you need. You might need to check some of the other classes in the library.